# How to set up vsvars32 environment variables?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2008, environment-variables, scons

I'm struggling with setting my scons environment variables for visual studio 2008.
Normally I do following:

```
%VS90COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat

or 

call %VS90COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat
```

And this works in my shell.

I try to do that in python using subprocess

```
subprocess.call([os.environ['VS90COMNTOOLS']+r"\vsvars32.bat"])
```

output:

```
d:\N\workspace>scons test
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 x86 tools.
KeyError: 'INCLUDE':
```

above invokes batch process, but environment variables are not inherited from it to my 'master process.

When i use:

```
subprocess.call([os.environ['VS90COMNTOOLS']+r"\vsvars32.bat"])
```

I get:

```
d:\N\workspace>scons test
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified:
  File "D:\N\workspace\SConstruct", line 17:
    subprocess.Popen(["call ", os.environ['VS90COMNTOOLS']+r"\vsvars32.bat"])
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 595:
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 821:
    startupinfo)
```

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a batch file that runs `vsvars32.bat` and then outputs the values in the form `VARNAME=value`, then have your Python script parse the values and inject them into `os.environ`.

This is done in python's own distutils module, [see the source here](http://hg.python.org/distutils2/file/0291648eb2b2/distutils2/compiler/msvc9compiler.py#l239).

Comment: I was not considering this way, but it seems that there is no way to do that using python subprocess library (no mystery hidden options;).
So i'll accept your answer.

Comment: The reason there's no way to do this is because each process has their own environment, and environments can only be handed down to child processes, not passed up to parent processes. So we use an "out-of-band" communication method to pass what the values *should* be to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer. An excerpt of my SConstruct:

```
for key in ['INCLUDE','LIB']:
    if os.environ.has_key(key):
        env.Prepend(ENV = {key.upper():os.environ[key]})
```

Please take care that variable names in Python are case-sensitive. Ensure that your `env['ENV']` dict has no duplicate variable names with different case, otherwise the Windows shell will only see one variant of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

A short code (Python 3) addition to the accepted answer:

```py
def vs_env_dict():
  vsvar32 = '{vscomntools}vsvars32.bat'.format(vscomntools=os.environ['VS140COMNTOOLS'])
  cmd = [vsvar32, '&&', 'set']
  popen = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  stdout, stderr = popen.communicate()
  if popen.wait() != 0:
    raise ValueError(stderr.decode("mbcs")) 
  output = stdout.decode("mbcs").split("\r\n")
  return dict((e[0].upper(), e[1]) for e in [p.rstrip().split("=", 1) for p in output] if len(e) == 2)
os.environ.update(vs_env_dict())
```

It works for me!

Comment: SCons should detect and setup the MSVC itself. If it's not it's a bug. You should not have to do this separate logic..